# Como enviar y recibir datos con una función que viaja en una prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando de editar una libreria para adaptarla a mis necesidades: https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range

Estoy haciendo uso de `<DateRangePicker />` y quiero agregar una funcionalidad: Que al hacer hover en una celda de cualquier dia del mes, se ejecute una funcion. Mientras se ejecuta esta funcion, el dia debe tener una clase `loading`, y cuando termina de hacerlo, puede retornar `true` o `false`. La idea es que si retorna `true` el calendario se comporte normalmente, pero si retorna `false` quiero deshabilitar esta fecha y mostrar un tooltip explicando al usuario que no es posible seleccionarla.

Mi intencion es poder pasarle al componente `<DateRangePicker />` una funcion por medio de una `prop`, algo como `onHoverCell`. Esta funcion pasa por algunos componentes, hasta llegar al componente `DayCell`.

Entonces tengo esto, en `DateRangePicker.js`

```
this.onHoverCell = day => {
      console.log('Funciona? ', day);
      return {
        status: false,
        loading: false,
      };
    };
 ...
    <DateRange
      ...otras props
      onHoverCell={this.onHoverCell}
    />
```

Luego de viajar a traves de algunos componentes, la funcion llega al componente donde la necesito, `DayCell`, en este componente devuelvo un `button`:

```
     <button
      type="button"
      onMouseEnter={() => this.props.onHoverCell(this.props.day)}
      ...otras props
    </button>
```

Esto funciona correctamente, puedo ver mi console `Funciona??` y la fecha correcta. Ahora, la cuestion es que yo necesito hacer una consulta a la API dentro de esta funcion, y de allí pueden existir 3 resultados posibles:

- `loading`, mientras la funcion carga.
- `true` si la funcion retorna true, el boton del dia debe tener el comportamiento de siempre
- `false` si la funcion retorna false, el boton debe tener alguna clase CSS que me permita des-habilitarlo (no es lo mismo que agregarle disabled al button, tengo que hacerlo con css) y debe mostrarse ademas del button, un tooltip mostrando un mensaje.

El tema es que no tengo idea de como, una vez recibido el dia en mi funcion `this.onHoverCell`, volver a retornarle al componente `DayCell` los datos necesarios para darle a los botones el estilo que quiero.

---

**Una forma de sintetizar el flujo que necesito es:**

1. Componente A pasa una función a un componente B
2. Componente B recibe esta función y la coloca en el evento `onMouseEnter` de un botón
3. Cuando se ejecuta el evento `onMouseEnter`, Componente B -> envía un dato al componente A
4. El Componente A ejecuta la función que pasamos al principio, y retorna un dato

***-> estoy trabado en esta parte <-***

- El Componente A pasa el dato recibido al componente B
- El Componente B setea un estado a partir de este dato que recibe

Comment: En el punto 3. del flujo `Cuando se ejecuta el evento onMouseEnter, Componente B -> envía un dato al componente A` cuando dices que el componente B envía un dato al componente A, lo que en realidad está pasando es que estás ejecutando la función que el componente A le pasó al componente B como callback. Por lo tanto, en el punto 4. El componente A no ejecuta esa función que pasó, si no que "maneja" su ejecución ya que la declaramos en el mismo componente A. El que la ejecuta con ciertos parámetros (Lo que tu llamas enviar datos) es el componente B.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior. En lo que estás trabado `El Componente A pasa el dato recibido al componente B` para hacer eso básicamente el componente B debe recibir un `prop` del componente A y reaccionar a los cambios del mismo, es decir, la forma clásica en la que funciona React. En resumen los componentes hijos se "comunican" hacia arriba a través de callbacks, y los componentes padres modifican el estado enviado a los componentes hijos (props)

Comment: eso mismo hice, agregue un estado en el componente padre que lo paso como prop al hijo, y este estado es seteado cuando se "maneja" la ejecucion de la funcion que pasé inicialmente. De esa forma en el hijo ahora tengo el valor que esperaba. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Genial, lo que te falta ahora es lo de consultar una API y en base a la respuesta ir cambiando el estado?

Comment: Si pero simulando estados veo que todo funciona como quiero, excepto una cosa. Voy a tener que hacer una pregunta aparte creo. Yo ejecuto una funcion cuando paso el mouse por encima de un dia, y esta funcion tarda un rato en ejecutarse. Yo quiero que si la vuelvo a llamar (porque puedo mover el mouse rapido y pasar por encima de muchos dias) se corte la llamada anterior y empiece de nuevo. Probando con un internet lento veo que si no hago eso, cuando termino de mover el mouse, van apareciendo los mensajes en los dias por los que fui pasando

Comment: Intente envolver la funcion cuando la ejecuto en el componente hijo en un debounce``onMouseEnter={debounce(() => this.props.onHoverCell(this.props.day), 200)}`` pero el resultado es igual que antes, pero con 200ms de atraso jaja

Comment: Estaría bueno ver en detalle lo que planteas, se ve interesante el problema

Comment: Aca la creé, supongo que no le falta info pero si la lees y crees que si, decime que agrego mas contexto. Gracias! https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/582422/puedo-detener-la-ejecucion-de-una-funcion-si-es-llamada-nuevamente

Comment: Estaba tratando de etiquetar la pregunta parece que es continuacion o la otra ya se puede cerrar, pero parece que me equivoque, saludos