# Puedo detener la ejecucion de una funcion, si es llamada nuevamente?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un calendario, y cuando hago hover en uno de sus dias ejecuto una funcion.

```
this.onHoverCell = async day => {
      try {
        if (day) {
          this.setState({
            resultSingleDay: {
              day,
              loading: true,
              result: false,
            },
          });
          const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
          const data = res.json();
          this.setState({
            resultSingleDay: {
              day,
              loading: false,
              result: true,
            },
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error');
      }
    };
```

Mi cuestion es la siguiente: Si yo paso el mouse por encima de un dia, la funcion se ejecuta. Pero es posible que una persona mueva el mouse rapido y ejecute la funcion multiples veces.

Yo quiero que cuando la funcion sea llamada nuevamente, no espere que termine la llamada anterior, sino que la corte y ejecute la llamada actual. Es posible esto?

En el componente hijo, asi es como se llama a la funcion anterior

```
    <button
      type="button"
      onMouseEnter={() => this.props.onHoverCell(this.props.day)}
     />
```

Intenté poner un debounce de esta manera

```
onMouseEnter={debounce(() => this.props.onHoverCell(this.props.day), 200)}
```

pero el problema persiste. Entonces buscaba la forma de `asesinar` cualquier funcion que este esperando ser resuelta, si es llamada nuevamente.

Comment: Quizás esta pregunta te sirva de ayuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23123138/how-to-perform-debounce

Comment: @AndresGardiol excelente, no conocia eso. Funciona perfecto, el tema es que no se exactamente donde poner ``this.controller.abort();``.

Comment: creo que cambiaste el link de la pregunta, no? voy a revisar en esto que me pasaste tambien, es react 14 asi que nada de hooks :/

Comment: @AndresGardiol crack, me anduvo perfecto la solucion con esta libreria: https://github.com/slorber/awesome-debounce-promise Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si, actualicé el link. Perfecto! Si te parece responde tu propia pregunta para ayudar a otros usuarios de SO en español

Answer (score 1):

El usuario Andres Gardiol me compartio en los comentarios una pregunta del sitio en ingles, y de ahi saque lo que necesitaba, aunque tuve que hacer un doble debounce para lograr el resultado esperado:

Instalé esta libreria en mi proyecto https://github.com/slorber/awesome-debounce-promise con `npm install awesome-debounce-promise --save`

Importo la libreria:

```
import AwesomeDebouncePromise from 'awesome-debounce-promise';
```

En el constructor del componente (es react 14):

```
this.searchAPI = () => fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
const searchAPIDebounced = AwesomeDebouncePromise(this.searchAPI, 500);

// esta funcion usa un debounce cuando obtengo res 
// (ejecuta las dos lineas que estan arriba de este comentario)
this.onHoverCell = async day => {
  try {
    if (day) {
      this.setState({
        resultSingleDay: {
          day,
          loading: true,
          result: false,
        },
      });
      const res = await searchAPIDebounced();
      const data = res.json();
      this.setState({
        resultSingleDay: {
          day,
          loading: false,
          result: true,
        },
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
};
```

Y finalmente defino la funcion que voy a pasar al componente hijo, encargada de ejecutarse cuando se haga `hover` en un boton:

```
this.asyncFunctionDebounced = AwesomeDebouncePromise(this.onHoverCell, 50);
```